# Find some records of results in other table - SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, find, conditional-statements, record

I have this code:

```
select J.JobID, J.Barcode,J.Bsn, FL.RequirementStatus as OverallResult,S.Name as operation_name, 
FL.Occurred, R.Name as parameter_name,
FL.LowerTorqueLimit, FL.Torque, FL.UpperTorqueLimit,
FL.LowerAngleLimit, FL.Angle, FL.UpperAngleLimit
from FastenerLog FL 
inner join Stations S on FL.StationID=S.StationID
inner join Jobs J on J.JobID = FL.JobID
inner join JobTypes JT on J.JobTypeID=JT.JobTypeID
inner join Requirements R on R.RequirementID=FL.RequirementID
INNER join FastenerStatusEnum FS on FS.FastenerStatus=FL.FastenerStatus
where FL.FastenerStatus=1 and R.Name like '40%'
and FL.Occurred between '02-20-2020 00:00:00' and '02-22-2020 23:59:00'
order by J.Barcode, FL.Occurred desc
```

It's working and I'm having this result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GRYH.jpg

But I want to add a clause to check in the other table when the Barcode of the result has the `operation_name` `T1XX-TR-OP60` (only for the first 9 lines that you can see in the picture).

***Pseudocode***: IF `operation_name` = `T1XX-TR-OP60` then check if Barcode exists in Barcode of Table-X.
Because I don't want to show the records if they are not in the Table-X (only for `T1XX-TR-OP60`).

***Note***: If `operation_name` is different to `T1XX-TR-OP60` nothing will happen for that record, just display it as currently shown.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, additional correlated where-clause should help. Something like this:

```
select J.JobID, J.Barcode,J.Bsn, FL.RequirementStatus as OverallResult,S.Name as operation_name, 
FL.Occurred, R.Name as parameter_name,
FL.LowerTorqueLimit, FL.Torque, FL.UpperTorqueLimit,
FL.LowerAngleLimit, FL.Angle, FL.UpperAngleLimit
from FastenerLog FL 
inner join Stations S on FL.StationID=S.StationID
inner join Jobs J on J.JobID = FL.JobID
inner join JobTypes JT on J.JobTypeID=JT.JobTypeID
inner join Requirements R on R.RequirementID=FL.RequirementID
INNER join FastenerStatusEnum FS on FS.FastenerStatus=FL.FastenerStatus
where FL.FastenerStatus=1 and R.Name like '40%'
and FL.Occurred between '02-20-2020 00:00:00' and '02-22-2020 23:59:00'
and (s.name <> 'T1XX-TR-OP60' 
     or (s.name = 'T1XX-TR-OP60' and exists(select 1 from Table-X tx where tx.barcode = j.barcode))
)
order by J.Barcode, FL.Occurred desc
```